# Failed to build image due to does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, docker

When I try to build the image from Windows powershell, there is some error as shown below. Can I ask what could be the reason for and solution to it?

````
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
ERROR: Service failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt update &&     apt upgrade -y &&     apt install -y  software-properties-common &&     add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa &&     apt update &&     apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk &&     apt install -y nano less &&     apt clean' returned a non-zero code: 100```
````

Comment: The reason because disco is now EOL, and they simply don't exist anymore on main server.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Liso, that's exactly the [reason](https://ubuntustudio.org/2020/01/ubuntu-studio-19-04-eol-in-one-week/)! When I change it to Unbuntu 18.04 (The latest LTS version) the problem is solved.